# how to make live stream function works with a generated variable each time?

Tags: pandas, multithreading, websocket, binance, python-binance

I want to run a binance live stream function that get a generated symbol from another function each time.
1- top gainer function: scan the market and get top price gainer coin each certain time.
2- live stream run function: get the symbol from the first function then start websocket to pull data each time with a new symbol comes from top gainer function.

here is the code:

<

```
import json,time, asyncio,websockets
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
import numpy as np

client = Client(api_key=pkey, api_secret=skey, tld='com', testnet=True)

interval = '1m'

data=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Coin','Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'no_trades','Quote_Volume','Complete'])

async def top_3gainer_coins():  
    try:
        print("Updating top gainer coins...")
        time.sleep(90)
        exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()
        spot_symbols = [
            symbol['symbol'] for symbol in exchange_info['symbols'] if symbol['isSpotTradingAllowed']
            and symbol['quoteAsset'] == 'USDT'
            and symbol['status'] == 'TRADING'  # Ensure the symbol is actively trading
            ]
        all_data = []
        for symbol in spot_symbols:
            try:
                data = (pd.DataFrame(client.get_klines(symbol=symbol, interval='5m', limit=12))).copy()
                data = data.iloc[:, [0, 4, 5, 8]]  # Keep only columns with timestamp, open, close, and volume
                data.columns = ['Date', 'Close', 'Volume', 'NoTrades']
                data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], unit='ms')
                for column in data.columns[1:]:
                    data[column] = pd.to_numeric(data[column])
                data['pricegain'] = (data.Close.pct_change() * 100).fillna(0)
                data['VGain'] = (data.Volume.pct_change() * 100).fillna(0)
                data['TPS'] = (data.NoTrades / 60).fillna(0)
                data.insert(1, 'Symbol', symbol)
                data = data.iloc[-2:]
                data = data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)  # Replace inf with NaN
                data = data.reset_index(drop=True)  # Reset the index for each symbol's data
                all_data.append(data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error fetching data for symbol {symbol}: {e}")
                continue
        if all_data:
            all_data = pd.concat(all_data)
            all_data = all_data.sort_values(by='pricegain', ascending=False)
            all_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
            all_data.index += 1

            top_gainer = all_data.head(1)      # Select the top 3 gainers            
            top_gainer_coins = top_gainer['Symbol'].tolist()   # Get the symbols of the top 3 gainers
            print(top_gainer_coins)
            print(f"Top 3 gainer coins\n{top_gainer.to_string()}")
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}") 
    return top_gainer_coins

def on_open(ws):
    #print(f'Opened connection for {ws.symbol}')
    pass

def on_close(ws):
    print(f'Closed connection for {ws.symbol}')

async def on_message(ws, msg):
    try:
        msg = json.loads(msg)
        start_time = pd.to_datetime(msg['k']['t'], unit='ms')
        symbol = msg['s']
        open_price = float(msg['k']['o'])
        high = float(msg['k']['h'])
        low = float(msg['k']['l'])
        close = float(msg['k']['c'])
        volume = float(msg['k']['v'])
        no_trades = float(msg['k']['n'])
        quote_volume = float(msg['k']['q'])
        complete = msg['k']['x']

        if complete:
            data.loc[len(data)] = [start_time, symbol, open_price, high, low, close, volume, no_trades, quote_volume, complete]
            print(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing message for symbol {symbol}: {e}")
async def run(symbol):
    print('system starts')
    try:  
        symbol= symbol.lower()
        print(f'Start working on coin: {symbol}')
        socket = f"wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{symbol}@kline_{interval}"
        async with websockets.connect(socket) as ws:
            while True:
                response = await ws.recv()
                on_message(ws, response)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error on run : {e}')
        pass
async def main():
    while True:
        try:
            symbols =await top_3gainer_coins()
            if symbols:
                # Create a list of tasks for the run function with the symbols from top gainers
                run_tasks = [asyncio.create_task(run(symbol)) for symbol in symbols]
                await asyncio.gather(*run_tasks)  # Wait for all run tasks to complete
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'error: {e}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'error: {e}')
```

> 

Comment: FYI, A "variable" is something in your source code. Unless your program is writing new source code, the things that it generates every certain time probably should not be called "variables." Maybe they are "objects." Or maybe... I don't know. Probably nobody is going to answer your question though unless you ammend it to show the actual code that you are asking about.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you are right, I have edited my question and added the code to be more clear and understandable.